# How to get a new variable of the same type of another variable with Golang

Tags: go, reflection

How can I do this? I want a function to return a variable with the same type as one of its arguments. I need something like the below:

```
type Whatever struct {
    Title string
}

hey:= Whatever{Title:"YAY"}
thetype := reflect.ValueOf(hey).Kind()

// This does not work
BB:= new(thetype)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a new value from a `reflect.Type` you can do it with `reflect.New`:

```
thetype := reflect.TypeOf(hey)
BB:= reflect.New(thetype)
```

This returns a `reflect.Value`
You can then for example use `.Interface()` and type assertions to get back to the original type.

Example on Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rL-Hm0IUpd

Comment: technically those are not the same type: https://play.golang.org/p/9Xk1Mdrg_V (though the original question is making the same value vs pointer too)

Comment: If he wants a value instead of a pointer he can use `reflect.Zero`. However as his source code uses `new` I imagined he wanted a pointer.

Comment: @JimB at first I thought that you were the one that answered as usual.